# Arrow with two tails and a latex arrow tip

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

How to draw an arrow with two tails in `tikzcd` (or `tikz`) with a `latex` arrow tip? If I use `\ar[Rightarrow]`, I get the default arrow tip. If I use `\ar[double]`, I can get a `latex` arrow tip, but the two tails are too close to each other.

[image]

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{commutative diagrams/.cd, arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=latex}}

\begin{document}

$\begin{tikzcd} A \ar{rr} \ar{dr} & \ar[Rightarrow]{d} & B \\
 & C \ar{ur} & \end{tikzcd}$

 $\begin{tikzcd} A \ar{rr} \ar{dr} & \ar[double]{d} & B \\
 & C \ar{ur} & \end{tikzcd}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `double distance`.

Comment: Oh yes, double distance = 0.3ex works. I will accept this as an answer, if you post it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `Rightarrow` is a [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd) option, `double` is a Ti*k*Z option and is usually used together with `double distance`/`double distance between line centers`/`double equal sign distance`.

It is worth noting that `double equal sign distance` will setup the double distance such that a doubled line is compatible with the equal sign (assuming the standard font.)

Following this remark, one may find that [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd) uses `double equal sign distance` to define `double line`. And then it uses `double line` to define `Rightarrow`/`Leftarrow`/`Leftrightarrow`/`Mapsto`/`Mapsfrom`/`equal`/`equals`.